# Are Will-o-the-Wisps immune to the Slumber hex?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Will-o-the-wisps have Immunity to Magic. The Slumber witch hex is a supernatural ability. Can a witch put a Will-o-the-Wisp to sleep?

My guess is yes even though it seems kind of silly.

Comment: The special ability "Immunity to Magic" is clarified later in the statblock for the creature. It is not blanket immunity to all magic, but rather specific spells.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The [wisp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/will-o--wisp) is not immune

Their immunity ability has the following text:

> Will-o'-wisps are immune to all spells and spell-like abilities that allow spell resistance, except magic missile and maze.

[Slumber](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes---3rd-party-publishers/hexes/common-hexes/hex-slumber-su) is a [supernatural ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-). Supernatural abilities are neither spells nor spell-likes, and don't allow spell resistance. They meet none of the criteria that an ability needs to meet for wisps to be immune.